# How to insert code into a vimoutliner file?

Tags: linux, vim, outliner, vimoutliner

How to insert code into a vimoutliner document (.otl)? Is there something like:

```
<code>
...
</code>
```

Comment: Seems not to be possible ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a "preformatted body text" block by starting a line with `;`, e.g.:

```
Hello world
    This is "Hello world" in Ruby
    ; def hello(name)
    ;   puts "Hello, #{name}!"
    ; end
```

According to the [docs](https://github.com/vimoutliner/vimoutliner/blob/c02aa85ef35122e6f994c959d08b586b435d1c25/doc/votl_readme.txt#L553-L557):

> The preformatted text marker, ;, is used to mark text that should not be
>   reformatted nor wrapped by VO or any post-processor. A post-processor would
>   use a fixed-space font, like courier, to render these lines. A post-processor
>   will probably not change the appearance of what you have written. This is
>   useful for making text picture, program code or other format-dependent text.

You can also use `<` for a "user-defined preformatted text" block, which allows you to give a "style" to the block (e.g. to label which language it's in):

```
Hello world
    This is "Hello world" in Haskell
    <Haskell
    <hello :: String -> IO ()
    <hello name = putStrLn ("Hello " ++ name ++ "!")
```

As implied by the docs, what actually happens to those text blocks depends to what you're doing with your outlines once written - if you're using some tool to process them into another form, you'd want to check what that tool does with preformatted text blocks.  I use a custom-written tool that takes the user-defined preformatted blocks and outputs syntax-highlighted HTML `<code>` tags.